# Set the image dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource, picturebox

In the `Image` property of a `picturebox` *(pbAdvertisingSpace)* I've added some images in `Embedded Resources` to my project.

However, my difficulty is trying to set the image of `pictureBox` dynamically with depending on the value of another property *(HoleNumber)*.  As you can see from my trial method below,

I've tried a few different ways to change the picture, but to date unsuccessfully.

Can anyone advise me on the correct way to access these images?

```
    private void SetAdvertisingLogo()
    {
        if (_getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 1 || _getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 8 || _getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 15)
        {
            pbAdvertisingSpace.Image.PropertyIdList.GetValue(7); 
        }
        else if (_getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 2 || _getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 9 || _getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 16)
        {
            pbAdvertisingSpace.Image.PropertyItems.ElementAt(9);
        }
        else if (_getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 3 || _getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 10 || _getPlayerDetail.HoleNumber == 17)
        {
            pbAdvertisingSpace.Image.PropertyItems.ElementAt(8);
        }
       etc...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        pbAdvertisingSpace.Image = Resources.yourImage;
```